# Not able to show menubar and title of the window in my PyQt5 application - how to fix?

Tags: pyqt5

In my PyQt5 application I have made a subclass of QMainWindow to customize the main window.
But with this design, I am not able to display the title of the main window and also not able to show the menu bar at the top.
If I uncomment the window.show() statement in my code, that pops-up 2 separate windows - and in one of them it can show and display the title and menu but my purpose is not met.
How can I show the title, menu and the QStackedLayout that I have created in one single window ?

Below is my code :

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, QRect, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QAction, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QWidget, QStackedLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class Ui(QWidget):

    def setupUi(self, Main):
        #print (dir(Main))
        self.setWindowTitle("My App")
        Main.setObjectName("Main")
        Main.setFixedSize(900, 500)
        self.width = 900
        self.height = 500

        self.setFixedSize(self.width, self.height)
        
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('&File')
       
        self.menu = QStackedLayout()

        self.mainMenu = QWidget()
        self.nextMenu = QWidget()

        self.mainMenuUi()
        self.nextMenuUi()

        self.menu.addWidget(self.mainMenu)
        self.menu.addWidget(self.nextMenu)

    def mainMenuUi(self):
        print ("Inside mainMenuUi")
        self.mainMenu.setFixedSize(self.width, self.height)
        self.mainMenuText = QLabel("welcome view", self.mainMenu)
        self.mainMenuText.setGeometry(QRect(30, 120, 480, 200))
        self.mainMenuText.setStyleSheet("font: 14pt Century Gothic")
        self.mainMenuText.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading|Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignTop)
        self.btn2 = QPushButton("Next", self.mainMenu)

    def nextMenuUi(self):
        print ("Inside nextMenuUi")
        self.nextMenu_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.nextMenu.setFixedSize(self.width, self.height)
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Back")
        self.nextMenu_layout.addWidget(self.btn1)
        self.nextMenu.setLayout(self.nextMenu_layout)


# Subclass QMainWindow to customize your application's main window
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My App window title")

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.menuWindow)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.menuWindow2)

    def menuWindow(self):

        self.menu.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def menuWindow2(self):

        self.menu.setCurrentIndex(1)



app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
#window.show()

app.exec()
```

Comment: Don't try to mimic the behavior of pyuic files, as it is completely pointless. Especially if you also do it by subclassing from QWidget and then try to use multiple inheritance, which is just *wrong*. Remove that `Ui` class, which is completely useless, and move the `setupUi` to `MainWindow`. You can also remove the `Main` argument of that function, since it's implied by `self`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, well ... I did as you suggested, removed Ui and moved setupUi to MainWindow. However, it does not solve the problem that I am facing. Everything is just working as before with one class less in the code. I still can't see the title and menu. And if I uncomment window.show(),I get 2 windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**Qt Main Window Framework**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework)
> ...
> Note: Creating a main window without a central widget is not supported. You must have a central widget even if it is just a placeholder.

---

What @musicamante wrote to you looks like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, \
    QAction, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QWidget, QStackedLayout, QStyle


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("My App window title")
        
        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('&File')        
        openFile = QAction(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MessageBoxCritical), 
            'Open', self)
        fileMenu.addAction(openFile)  

        self.width = 900
        self.height = 500
        self.resize(self.width, self.height)

        self.mainMenu = QWidget()
        self.nextMenu = QWidget()
        
        self.mainMenuUi()
        self.nextMenuUi()
        
        self.menu = QStackedLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.menu.addWidget(self.mainMenu)
        self.menu.addWidget(self.nextMenu)

        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.menuWindow)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.menuWindow2)

    def mainMenuUi(self):
        self.mainMenuText = QLabel("welcome view", self.mainMenu)
        self.mainMenuText.setGeometry(QRect(30, 120, 480, 200))
        self.mainMenuText.setStyleSheet("font: 14pt Century Gothic")
        self.mainMenuText.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading|Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignTop)
        self.btn2 = QPushButton("Next", self.mainMenu)

    def nextMenuUi(self):
        self.nextMenu_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Back")
        self.nextMenu_layout.addWidget(self.btn1)
        self.nextMenu.setLayout(self.nextMenu_layout)

    def menuWindow(self):
        self.menu.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def menuWindow2(self):
        self.menu.setCurrentIndex(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, It works as per my requirement . The key was self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget) ...